# (verification) Cauchy sequence can have at most one cluster points

Tags: proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Suppose Cauchy sequence $x_n$ holds more than $2$ different cluster points - $x_k$ and $x_l$.

Then by definition of the cluster points of the sequence, it means that $x_k$ holds more than two convergent point $x_k$ and $x_l$ for $k,l \gt$ certain $N$.

if $x_k \neq x_l$ then $d(x_k,x_l) = e >0$ and it is contradictory to the Cauchy property which for $k,l>N$ $d(x_k,x_l) \lt e \;\forall e\gt0$

Comment: What metric space is this happening in ? If it isn't a complete metric space (e.g. the reals are complete) then a Cauchy sequence need not converge to a limit - I assume that a limit is what you refer to as a convergent point.

Answer (score 0):

The cluster points need not be terms of the sequence. You have to do some more work.

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are different cluster points, say $a<b$. Set $\varepsilon=(b-a)/4$.

Since the sequence is Cauchy, there exists $N$ such that, for $m,n>N$,
$$
|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon
$$
On the other hand, since $a$ and $b$ are cluster points, there exist $k,l>N$ such that
$$
|x_k-a|<\varepsilon
\qquad
|x_l-b|<\varepsilon
$$
Now find the contradiction.

> $$b-a=|b-x_l+x_l-x_k+x_k-a|\le|b-x_l|+|x_l-x_k|+|x_k-a|\le\frac{3}{4}(b-a)$$

Comment: I can't not find contradiction. how to construct it?

Comment: @delog Well, my estimate was poor and $(b-a)/4$ was needed.

Comment: no if I truly understand what you intend, that numerator would not be matter. thx

Comment: Isn't it possible that k,l < N ? I thought the definition is that for arbitrary distance away there must be another point, but it doesn't say where in the indexing of the sequence that point needs to be.

Comment: @IntegrateThis We want to find a contradiction and using $k,l>N$ yields it.